# prediction shape is incorrect

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression, mean-square-error

While calculating mean_squared_error from scikit-learn I am getting an error

```
def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.001, n_iters=1000):
    self.lr = learning_rate
    self.n_iters = n_iters
    self.weights = None
    self.bias = None

def fit(self, X, y):
    n_samples, n_features = X.shape  # shape of X is (100,1) so there are 100 samples and only 1 feature

    self.weights = np.zeros(n_features)
    self.bias = 0

    for _ in range(self.n_iters):
        y_predicted = np.dot(X, self.weights) + self.bias

        dw = (1 / n_samples) * np.dot(X.T, (y_predicted - y))
        db = (1 / n_samples) * np.sum(y_predicted - y)
        self.weights = self.lr * dw - self.weights
        self.bias = self.lr * db - self.bias

def predict(self, X):
    return X.dot(self.weights) + self.bias
```

'''

```
 X = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
 X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
 print(X.shape)

 y = [(-19 * i - 9) for i in X]
 y = np.array(y)

 # adding noise to the data
 noise = np.random.normal(1, 0)  # Adding guassian noise to y with mean 1 and std 0
 y = y + noise

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
test_size=0.2, random_state=1234)
print(X_test.shape)
regression = LinearRegression(learning_rate=0.01)
regression.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regression.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred.shape)
mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred)
```

Last line throws the error:

```
ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different numbers of output (1!=80)
```

Here are the shapes of my variables:

```
(100, 1)  # X.shape
(20, 1)   # y_test.shape
(20, 80)  # y_pred.shape
```

Comment: There is no MSE calculation shown in your code; please see how to create a [mre].

Comment: Hello Sir! I have updated the code I have imported mean_squared_error from sci-it learn and after giving parameters it is showing this error "   raise ValueError(
ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different number of output (1!=80) "

Comment: 1) Since you are using scikit-learn and `LinearRegression`, what exactly is the first code snippet, and how is it related with the rest of your code? 2) There is no point in including `print` statements in your code without their *output*, please update your post with the outputs of `print(y_pred.shape)` and `print(y_test.shape)`

Comment: The first code snippet is a Linear Regression class that I have write from scratch , the only thing I am using from scikit learn is mean-squared-error

Comment: You should have explained that in the post, plus you are missing the class header; please be clear and complete, and don't leave readers and possible respondents to guess. Please update your post accordingly

Comment: @MohsinMehmood You should have a major issue in your LinearRegression implementation. In a correct implementation,  the return value from `regression.predict(X_test)` call, should be of the size of (#x_test_rows,1) where #x_test_rows is the number of rows in the x_test. that said, you should have y_pred of the shape (20,1). I suspect you need to review the linear algebra calculations in your  LinearRegression implementation.